# With JQueryUI Draggable, how to select object being dragged

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using JQueryUI draggable and I would like to be able to add styling to the draggable element while it is being dragged.  I have tried variations on this code:

```
$(".ui-widget-content").draggable({
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).css("width", "50px");
  });
```

However, my attempts have failed and I believe it it because I don't know how to get the draggable element from the ui object.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for extra JavaScript. Just use this CSS selector:

```css
.ui-draggable-dragging {
    /*
    This class is applied to the element while it is being dragged.
    This is done automatically by jQueryUI.
    */

    width: 50px;
}
```

Read the docs here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#overview-main

Comment: Ah yes, of course, thank you.  Also, need to use the event 'drag' instead of 'dragstart.'  I could make the edit to the question, but perhaps it makes more sense for you to edit the answer?